# C++ RGB values from pixel selected by user-using seekg

Tags: c++, rgb, seekg

I need to create a program that loads a .raw image (generic 100x100 image), asks the user to select an (x, y) coordinate within the range, and display the red, green, and blue values for said pixel using the seekg function. I'm at a loss as to how to get the rgb values from the pixel. I've gone through every chapter of the textbook that we've covered so far, and there is nothing about retreiving rgb values.

The code asking for the coordinates and giving an error message if outside the range is working fine. Only when I try to come up with the code for using seekg/getting the rgb values am I running in to trouble. I've looked at different questions on the site, and there is good information here, but I've not see any answers using seekg in order to get the rgb values.

I'm not looking for anyone to produce the code for me, just looking for some guidance and a push in the right direction.

```
loc = (y * 100 + x) * 3;  // code given by professor with 100 being the width of the image
imageRaw.seekg(loc, ios::beg);
```

And then I'm at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that after you execute the seekg( ), the file read pointer is positioned at the first byte of the 3 that, when taken together, give the pixel's color. What's the very next thing you might do?

Comment: That's where I'm lost. I'm feeling really dumb at the moment. This is not a difficult assignment, I know this, yet something is not clicking for me.

Answer (score 1):

From there, you probably need to read three bytes, which will represent the red, green, and blue values. You haven't told us enough to be sure of the order; green is almost always in the middle, but RGB and BGR are both fairly common.

From a practical viewpoint, for a picture of this size you don't normally want to use seekg at all though. You'd read the entire image into memory, and lookup the values in the vector (or array, if you insist) that stores the data.

Comment: I would like to expand on this answer by saying, you need to advance by what ever your bit depth your image is. Your advance value may not be a byte (8 bit color) pictures can range from 2 bit - 32 bit color So you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: … I guess if you're only going to check one pixel, it doesn't make sense to bring the image into memory. But if you were going to do any real work with the image, you'd bring it into memory (in a vector/array, or, possibly via `mmap` if you're on Unix)

Comment: @Shadow: It's 3 bytes/pixel, as you can see from the formula in the question. Note the * 3 in it. But what you say is true in general of course. (And I suppose could be true here, nothing says the 24 bits have to spread equally amongst the three channels. Or that they even have to be RGB values, YUV, HSV, etc. is possible too. But that'd be an evil professor.)

Comment: @derobert I agree, I am glad the problem isn't any harder than it needs to be. It's typical of a real life situation.